# Can I take legal actions against my roommate for not letting me have electricity?

Tags: canada, police, rental-property, harassment, quebec

My roommate has decided to turn off the electrical breaker (which is situated in her bedroom) of my room because I've allegedly forgotten to turn off a light in my room before leaving for work. I've contacted her politely to ask if she could turn on it again to no avail.

My next steps are going be to either turn it back on while she's away, although she's rarely gone, or to warn her I'm about to walk into her room to turn it back on and do it myself but I'm fairly confident she'll just turn it back off if I do that.

So, can I call the police, or the landlord do anything about this?

Comment: I doubt that you'll find the police interested in this since it's not in any way criminal.  Since it's entirely a civil matter, you could, obviously, file a case but what is your expected outcome?  It might be better to work things out between the two of you or, failing that, move out.

Comment: Not a good apartment-mate...

Answer (score 1):

Small claims court is cheap. Extension cord, battery, etc could all be brought up in case against roommate. Document, document, document, now! Observations, times, responses, video, etc.

Depending on your relationship with landlord (are you leasing or are you subletting?) most would love to know tenants behavior with **their** breaker box.

They also make locks for breaker boxes, but I would advise against this without landlord consent.